# c++11 promise object gets invalid, but its future object neither returns value nor throw exception

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, get, future

I've got this test code to see, if a promise object is out of lifecycle, what happen to its future object:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void getValue(future<int>& future) {
    cout << "sub process 1 \n";
    try {
        cout << "sub process 2 \n";
        int value = future.get();
        cout << "sub process 3\n";
        cout << value << endl;
    } catch (future_error &e) {
        cerr << e.code() << '\n' << e.what() << endl;
    } catch (exception e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
    cout << "sub process 4\n";
}
int main() {
    thread t;
    {
        promise<int> plocal;
        future<int> flocal = plocal.get_future();
        t = thread(getValue, ref(flocal));
    }
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that in `getValue` function, it either prints future::get result, or throws out runtime exception and prints exception info, because `plocal` has been destructed in "main".

Acturally, this program prints:

```
sub process 1
sub process 2
```

and ends.

Comment: You're in undefined behavior land.  All outcomes are valid.

Comment: What in this code is doing a `throw runtime_error`?

Comment: Looks like code that's trying to break things on purpose. Behavior is dependent on actual order of thread scheduling, and in one of those cases your thread may indeed well access memory on the stack that's no longer containing your local scoped variables. Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future that might help you if you want shared access to a future (extend its lifetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not about `std::promise` or `std::future` behavior.

You simply cause a data race (and consequently undefined behavior) by passing the `flocal` object by-reference to the thread, accessing it in the thread, but also destroying it in the main thread without any synchronization.

This doesn't work no matter what type or kind of object `flocal` is.

Pass the `std::future` by-value via `std::move`:

```
void getValue(future<int> future)

/*...*/

t = thread(getValue, std::move(flocal));
```

With this change the destructor of `std::promise` will store a `std::future_error` exception in the shared state and `get` on the future in the thread will receive and throw it.

---

If you pass something with `std::ref` to a thread you *always* have to make sure that the referenced object outlives the thread or you need to make sure that there is some synchronization mechanism to determine when the main thread may destroy the object.